# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

My goal is to scrape the stock price of the company which user will enter in the input box, but I am getting this error.

When I'm running the code without input block it's running fine,
I don't know what's wrong with it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
    
inp=input('company name')+":nse"
url1="https://www.google.com/finance/quote/"+inp.upper()
print(url1)
main_links=requests.get(url).text
soups=BeautifulSoup(main_link,'lxml')
stock_price=soup.find('div',class_="YMlKec fxKbKc").text
print(stock_price.text)
```

Output:

```
    company nametatamotors:nse
    https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TATAMOTORS:NSE
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    /var/folders/nz/ccxxqn4x7rn2k4784tjpdd2c0000gn/T/ipykernel_2968/3667408284.py in <module>
          5 soups=BeautifulSoup(main_link,'lxml')
          6 stock_price=soup.find('div',class_="YMlKec fxKbKc")
    ----> 7 print(stock_price.text)
    
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1):

*You have typos in your code, fix it*

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

inp = input('company name ') + ":nse"
url = "https://www.google.com/finance/quote/" + inp.upper()

main_links = requests.get(url=url)

soups = BeautifulSoup(main_links.content, features='html.parser')

stock_price = soups.find('div', class_="YMlKec fxKbKc")
print(stock_price.text)
```